# Impact on performance when having multiple returns

Tags: assembly, x86, micro-optimization

Take a look at below scenario.

```
;some code 
 test reg1,reg2
je jump1
 ;do something
 add rsp,20
 pop rdx
 ret
jump1:
 ;do something
 cmp reg2,reg3
 jg jump2
 add rsp,20
 pop rdx
 ret
jump2:
 ;do something
 add rsp,20
 pop rdx
 ret
```

Similar assembles are not commonly found in disassembled codes. Perhaps compilers handle such much efficiently.

Can having multiple return statements affect performance? 
What are the possible performance outcomes using a single return with `jmp` compared to the above?

Comment: too broad, performance is not that generic, clearly if there were an additional jump at the end of all but one case that will take more time, mess with the pipe, etc.  but for that specific target would it be noticable or buried in the noise?  x86 has a lot of overhead and would probably put this in the noise but there are leaner meaner platforms where you would be able to detect this.  and the problem with benchmark/tests like this is there can be one that would show one result and another that shows another result.

Comment: Depending on exactly what "do something" entails, you might also take a look at [cmov](https://github.com/xiadz/cmov).

Comment: **David Wohlferd** [Here](https://pastebin.com/V8VDuzkf) is a code

Comment: What is that code on your link supposed to do?  That looks way too small to be stand-alone function written in asm (so it can't inline); use intrinsics.  Also, use `pcmpeqb/w/d` to set a register to all-ones, not `pcmpeqq xmm0,xmm0` - qword can't run on as many ports on Zen, and requires SSE4.1.  R8 and R9 are call-clobbered; you don't need to push/pop them, unless you're using a custom asm calling convention.

Comment: converting pcmpgtq xmm0,xmm1 to non SSE42 code

Comment: A branchy emulation as a whole function seems pretty inefficient.  Pretty sure you could build that branchlessly out of SSE2 `pcmpgtd` and `pcmpeqd` with some shuffles, maybe with a constant to range-shift the low dwords of each qword from unsigned to signed before the `pcmpgtd`.  But anyway, if you're going to bother emulating it, might as well make it work with SSE2 instead of requiring SSE4.1 for `pcmpeqq` for no reason at all.

Comment: Primarily my goal was to minimize the use of stack & retain the values of all gpr except the first operand. pcmpeqd I will change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "tail duplication" optimization.  Some compilers do do this sometimes.  e.g. [LLVM blog post about it](http://elegantc.blogspot.com/2016/05/tail-duplication-with-llvm.html)

It's generally a good thing when your function epilogues are small (only 1 pop) so it doesn't cost much, especially on modern x86 with it's large caches and good code density (`ret` and `pop` are single-byte).  Although if only one path through the function is expected to be "hot", maybe better to have the other one jmp to the hot one to save a small amount of uop-cache space.

It saves one taken `jmp` on that path out of the function.  The performance impact of that depends on the surrounding code, as always for a deeply pipelined superscalar out-of-order CPU!

If multiple paths through a function could be hot depending on how your function is used, they can both/all be fully efficient.

---

You can also do it for loops that have a branch inside the loop: duplicate the `dec/jcc` or whatever at the bottom of the loop instead of jumping to a common `dec/jcc`.  (Don't forget to handle the fall-through path in both / all cases!)